# Call multiple .exe from Python

Tags: python, process

I have a problem where I want to call multiple .exe files from Python at once and one .exe has like 5 arguments. How can I call it? I tried 
`os.system("process.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4")` which works
but it can only launch one process at time and I also tried subprocess.run, however while it can call process like `subprocess.run("process.exe")` I can't seem to find solution how to send arguments like `subprocess.run("process.exe arg1 arg2 arg3")`. I need it to also open commandline as stdout which os.system command can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to spawn multiple processes simultaneously ("asynchronously", "in parallel"), use

```
p = subprocess.Popen("<command> <args>", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which instantly returns the Popen instance (object representing the spawned process).

`shell=True` allows you to pass the command as a "simple string" (e.g. `"myprog arg1 arg2"`). Without `shell=True` you must pass the list of arguments, including the name of a program as a first arg (e.g. `["myprog", "arg1", "arg2"]`).

`stdout=PIPE` ensures stdout capturing in a pipe (a file-like object in Python terms), which may be accessed via `p.stdout`. Use can read the output of your program via `p.stdout.read().decode()`, but note that this call is *blocking*, i.e. it awaits the program to stop, so in your case make sure that you have spawned all necessary processes before reading their outputs.

In order to await the program without reading its output, use `p.wait()`.

More information in Python docs: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I have been looking for...is there any chance that it an also open cmd and print stdout into that command line?

Comment: Do you want to pass some text into the **stdin** of the program? Then pass `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` option to the Popen constructor, and use `p.stdin` as a file-like object, e.g. `p.stdin.write("some text input".encode())`. Also, take a look at [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method, but note this is _blocking_, so in your case it is better to stick to the solution with pipes.